# How to dynamically loop values to filter pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to loop my df.columns so that i can dynamically apply condition to my every column through loop, i am not able to loop my column names in condition.

df:

```
   B1    B2    B3   B4   B5
   9     0     5    6    7
   8     7     6    4    8
   0     9     8    6    6
   1     0     7    6    3

condition = [(df['B1'] == 0)| (df['B1'].isnull==False),
             (df['B1'] == 8)| (df['B1'].isnull==True),
             (df['B1'] == 6)| (df['B1'].isnull==False)]

values = [999,444,555]
```

I used to do this:

```
df['B1'] = np.select(condition , values) # Seperately for every column.
```

I am trying:

```
for i in df.columns:
    df[i] = np.select(condition, values) # how can i able to loop i in condition, since condition is constant
```

Output for B1:

```
   B1    B2    B3   B4   B5
   999   0     5    6    7 
   999   7     6    4    8
   999   9     8    6    6
   999   0     7    6    3
```

Comment: Could you please describe you desired output? How ahould the result look like?

Comment: @mosc9575 i have added the output for one column "B1"

Comment: Every single value has to go through condition, which ever condition satisfies, it will change value. #  of condition should be equal to # of values always.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a dictionary to `.eq()` to check equality of different columns with different values:

```
>>> df.eq({'B1': 0, 'B2': 7, 'B3': 6, 'B4': 4, 'B5': 7})
      B1     B2     B3     B4     B5
0  False  False  False  False   True
1  False   True   True   True  False
2   True  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False
```

Similarly you can then do that after `.isna()`:

```
>>> df.isna().eq({'B1': False, 'B2': False, 'B3': True, 'B4': False, 'B5': False})
     B1    B2     B3    B4    B5
0  True  True  False  True  True
1  True  True  False  True  True
2  True  True  False  True  True
3  True  True  False  True  True
```

And then finally combine both with `|`

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use [`mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), this replaces a value, where a condition is `True`. If you loop over your conditions and values, I think you get, what you need.

```
conditions = [(df == 0)| (df.isnull==False),
             (df == 8)| (df.isnull==True),
             (df == 6)| (df.isnull==False)]

values = [999,444,555]        
    
for condition, value in zip(conditions, values):
    df.mask(condition, value, inplace=True)
```

The output for your example is this

```
    B1   B2   B3   B4   B5
0    9  999    5  555    7
1  444    7  555    4  444
2  999    9  444  555  555
3    1  999    7  555    3
```